# Adding header with username into request to backend in wso2 apimanager for all service

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using apimanger 1.9.

I read this already : [Add header with username into request to backend in wso2 apimanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755852/add-header-with-username-into-request-to-backend-in-wso2-apimanager).

I am able to add and forward username to backend in wso2 apimanager for specific service; but I want this for all service. I am modifying `admin--<api_name>_<version>.xml` for all services(50 services), which is very much manual. Something it leads to manual error.

Is there a single place configuration where I can set this (forward username to backend endpoint) for all service?

One more question - if I create and publish the APIs using "Publisher API" feature, is there a way to post something to set up the add header for each API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the velocity_template.xml which decides the template of an API. Please read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484006/programmatically-add-custom-handler-in-wso2-api-manager/31487527#31487527) given to a similar requirement. You need to modify the relevant section in the velocity_template.xml.

Comment: Understood the concept. I will and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to do this using custome handler and velocity_template.xml. One thing I want to share. Please don't remove authentication handler as it is setting END_USER_NAME. So if anyone wish to pass username please use authentication handler first and then custom handler.